# Is there a painless way to get self-loop decorations on mathematical symbols?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, arrows

In mathematics, we often write

```
X \rightarrow Y
```

to mean a function from X to Y. Now I'd like to denote a function from X to X via a looping-arrow decoration on the top right-hand corner of X.

Is there a painless way to do this?

Comment: It is surely possible. My recommendation is: don't do it. It's useful on a blackboard where you can comment it instantly. In a printed text, just repeat `X`, and if `X` is a complicated beast, give it a name. You don't want your text to be extremly dense in information, so give it a bit of a space :)

Comment: Assume `Y = X` ?

Comment: I agree with @tohecz that this is going to be ugly and distracting. It's just mapping information. They can survive with reading it twice?

Answer (score 7):

This just builds on Pier's answer, so as to prevent it from mucking up the surrounding formatting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\LoopFunction}[1]{%
  \renewcommand\stacktype{L}%
  \renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}%
  \renewcommand\stackalignment{l}%
  \setbox0\hbox{$#1$}%
  \stackon[2pt]{\usebox0}{\hspace{\the\wd0}\hspace{-1.6ex}%
    \tikz \node {} edge [in=30,out=60,loop] node {} ();}%
}
\begin{document}
$x\LoopFunction{A}y\LoopFunction{BCD}z$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using Pier's hint of `[in=60,out=30,loop]` gives something more pleasing to barbara's sensibilities, I think.

[image]

Note, per percusse's comment, that the decoration does not affect horizontal spacing of the surrounding text, but it does affect the vertical spacing.  While I would not recommend it, one could `\smash` the `tikz` decoration to make its apparent height zero.

---

**SUPPLEMENT**

Per the request of a commenter to make it work for super and sub scripts, I provide the following.  I added a macro `\uLoopfunction`, specifically for subscripts, as one cannot really loop above the subscript.

Also required was the ability to capture the proper `\scriptstyle` sizing of sub- and super-scripts, which I did with `scalerel`'s `\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\newcommand{\LoopFunction}[1]{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackengine{\dimexpr8\LMpt-6pt}{\usebox0}{\hspace{\the\wd0}\hspace{-1.6ex}%
    \tikz \node {} edge [in=60,out=30,loop] node {} ();}{O}{l}{F}{T}{L}%
}}
\newcommand{\uLoopFunction}[1]{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \rule[-\dp0]{0pt}{\dimexpr\dp0+\ht0}%
  \stackengine{\dimexpr\normalbaselineskip+2pt}{\usebox0}{\hspace{\the\wd0}\hspace{-1.6ex}%
    \tikz \node {} edge [in=-60,out=-30,loop] node {} ();}{U}{l}{F}{T}{L}%
}}
\begin{document}
$x^{\LoopFunction{A}}y_{\uLoopFunction{12}}\LoopFunction{BCD}z$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: surrounding as in Left/Right but not Up/Down?

Comment: i really don't know what i'm talking about, but it seems more logical to me that the arrowhead would be on the other end of the arrow.

Comment: @percusse  I could `\smash` the over-stacked content, but I don't know if that would please the OP or not.

Comment: @barbarabeeton  I just took Pier's existing decoration.  I don't know `tikz` to change the decoration, but clearly, a different one could be substituted.  Spacings might have to be adjusted...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: the "inversion" of the arrowhead is easily done: `[in=60,out=30,loop]`

Comment: This solution looks good in normal text, but doesn't work well in subscripts. The size and spacing is way off.

Comment: @PaulWintz Please see the **SUPPLEMENT** I added to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\LoopFunction}[1]{ \tikz \node {${\displaystyle #1}$} edge [in=30,out=60,loop] node {} ();
}

\begin{document}

\LoopFunction{A}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Please note that what follows is not an elegant way at all. I manually adjusted the angle of the incoming/leaving portion of the line and then inserted negative spaces `\!` to improve the kerning appearance. If the `\smash{}` command were to give problems, remove it from the command definition and use `\smash{\LoopFunction{<argument>}}` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\LoopFunction}[1]{\smash{\tikz \node [baseline=n.base,inner sep=0pt] (n) {${\displaystyle #1}$} edge [in=45,out=15,loop] node [inner sep=0pt] {} ();}$\!\!\!\!\!$
}

\begin{document}

This is a very long line to see what happens when the newly defined command, whose output is \LoopFunction{A}, is put in inline sentences.\\
Here is the second line to confirm a right behaviour.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe; can we prevent it from mucking up the surrounding formatting?

Answer (score 2):

With `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newcommand{\LoopFunction}[1]{\begin{tikzcd}
    #1\ar[in=30,out=60,loop]
    \end{tikzcd}}
\begin{document}
\LoopFunction{A}
\end{document}
```

[image]